# Simple ANTLR Preprocessor

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to create a simple preprocessor in ANTLR.  My grammar looks like this:

```
grammar simple_preprocessor;

ifdef_statement : POUND_IFDEF IDENTIFIER ;
else_statement : POUND_ELSE ;
endif_statement : POUND_ENDIF ;

preprocessor_statement :
    ifdef_statement
        code_block
    else_statement
        code_block
    endif_statement
    ;

code_file : (preprocessor_statement | code_block)+ EOF ;

code_block : TEXT ;

POUND_IFDEF : '#IFDEF';
POUND_ELSE : '#ELSE';
POUND_ENDIF : '#ENDIF';

IDENTIFIER : ID_START ID_CONTINUE* ;

TEXT : ~[\u000C]+ ;

fragment ID_START : '_' | [A-Z] | [a-z] ;
fragment ID_CONTINUE : ID_START | [0-9] ;

WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

Then I parse the following using the code_file() rule:

```
#IFDEF one
    print "1"
#ELSE
    print "2"
#ENDIF
```

The string tree looks like this:

```
(code_file (code_block \n#IFDEF one\n    print "1"\n#ELSE\n    print "2"\n#ENDIF\n) <EOF>)
```

Not what I want, because the preprocessor tokens are being treated as text and match the code_block rule.

I read the "Islands in the Stream" chapter in the ANTLR book, and the XML example makes sense, but it relies on TEXT not containing two specific characters:

```
TEXT : ~[<&]+ ;
```

If I really have to, I suppose I could exclude the # character:

```
TEXT : ~[#]+ ;
```

But I'm hoping there's a better way to tell ANTLR to exclude my preprocessor tokens so it can distinguish them from generic code.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lexical mode to separate the preprocessor directives from the ordinary text definition of your base grammar. Use the `\n#` and next `\n` as your mode guards.

```
PStart : '\n#' -> channel(HIDDEN), pushMode(PreProc) ;

mode PreProc ;

PIFDEF : 'IFDEF' PTEXT* ;
PELSE  : 'ELSE'  ;
PENDIF : 'ENDIF' ;
PTEXT  : [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ ;
PEOL   : [\r\n]+       -> channel(HIDDEN), popMode ;
PWS    : [ \t]+        -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
// maybe PCOMMENT ?
```

**Update** - to consolidate the full text of the directives into single tokens:

```
PIFDEF : 'IFDEF' PTEXT* PEOL -> popMode ;
PELSE  : 'ELSE'  PEOL -> popMode ;
PENDIF : 'ENDIF' PEOL -> popMode ;

PTEXT  : [ \ta-zA-Z0-9_-]+ ;
PEOL   : [\r\n]  ;
```

This is not typically the direction you want to go - generally you want to have greater decomposition rather than less. For example, this might be better while still producing visible EOLs.

```
mode PreProc ;

PIFDEF : 'IFDEF' ;
PELSE  : 'ELSE'  ;
PENDIF : 'ENDIF' ;
PTEXT  : [a-zA-Z0-9_-]+ ;
PEOL   : '\r'? '\n'    -> popMode ;
PWS    : [ \t]+        -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
PCMT   : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

This way the preproc command tokens are discrete and a sequence of one or more PTEXTs contain only the preproc identifier.  Emitting PEOLs appears redundant, but is not necessarily wrong. Parser rules to demonstrate:

```
preproc : ifdef | else | endif ;
ifdef   : PIFDEF PTEXT+ PEOL   ; // the rules are unambiguous
else    : PELSE  PEOL          ; // even without matching the PEOLs
endif   : PENDIF PEOL          ;
```

Comment: Thanks, modes looks like the right approach.  I tried this yesterday but it didn't work the way I needed -- most likely something I was doing incorrectly.  Thanks for posting an example -- this will be helpful!

Comment: Hi @GRose, your PTEXT definition does not include \r\n, but what if you need those inside of the text contained within the preprocessor tokens?